# Qt Dependency Visualizer

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, dependencies, code-visualization

I have a lot of classes which interact with other classes through signal&slot mechanism, composition, inheratance etc.

I wonder, is there any tool which visualizes(such as:UML-like diagrams) dependencies between classes in source code especially for Qt based codes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such tool is codedrawer for C++(http://www.codedrawer.com/).It is not specifically for QT though, but I hope it should work as per your need. Actually I am myself looking our for tools which are similar in nature, adding the link for followup just in case some good stuff shows up.
[Code refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777016/code-refactoring)

Comment: I tried codedrawer, but graphs are a little messy, it is not very clear who uses who.

Comment: CodeDrawer looks interesting - I could use something like that - but is non-linux,  Microsoft only.